# How to modify Django CMS admin panel?

Tags: django, django-cms

How may I widen the searchbox in Django CMS admin?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0KmF.png)

Comment: You would have to either change the css from the package (which is bad practice, as you will lose when you update the package) or add your own style sheet to the admin that overrides the styling. Django CMS haven't given you a way to change that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify additional CSS to be loaded as part of the admin page.

For example, see below an example loading both CSS and JS files:

```
class ImageGalleryAssetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ... 
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/xxx/enhance_admin.js',)
        css = {
          'all': ('admin/css/xxx/list_view.css',)
        }

admin.site.register(ImageGalleryAsset, ImageGalleryAssetAdmin)
```

You can then just find ID of your search box and specify CSS to change its looks.